# Loading Aurical fonts without generating a font warning

Tags: fonts, warnings

I've got a document where I load in the **aurical** package.  However, whenever I use the fonts this defines, I get a Font Warning telling me that the font shape has been scaled.  For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{aurical}
\begin{document}
\Fontamici Test!
\end{document}
```

yields:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/AmiciLogo/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 11.99997pt on input line 4.
```

What's the right way to use this set of fonts so that it doesn't generate a warning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LaTeX font setup is rather chatty: that's more of an informative note than a warning. The fd file for that font specifies it should be loaded 1.2 times the requested size and by default latex tells you this.

The relevant lines are:

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{AmiciLogo}{m}{n}{<-> [1.2] AmiciLogo}{}
```

Using the `s` scaling function rather than the default empty one stops the warning.

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{AmiciLogo}{m}{n}{<-> s * [1.2] AmiciLogo}{}
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  I'd forgotten about those subtleties of font loading.